# How to set an aspx page as homepage in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on  a web application, its default homepage is located in Views>>Home>>Index.cshtml. Its created by default. Now i need to replace it with login.aspx page, so that when a user visit my website, it automatically redirects him to login.aspx page. I am new to MVC and C#, please prove me a solution in detail. If you can write code, it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: this is not a case of replacing the default home page, it's a case of implementing an authentication system with the ability to redirect users who aren't logged in. Luckily MVC provides such a thing out of the box. Simply replacing the default home page doesn't by itself provide any security, because the user can simply type in the name of a different page instead. You need a whole system which checks the user's login status every time they make any kind of request to the application. . The default home page can stay the same, it's just that anyone not authenticated will have to log in first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick you can use :

Make no changes to the default route settings in RouteConfig.cs file which is as follow.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And in ActionResult Index of Home Controller you can set your authorization clause.

If you are managing it using **Session Variable** then you can set :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["Login"] == false)
            {
                return Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
}
```

Or if you are using MVC Authorization then you can set Action as `[Authorize]`.

**NOTE:** This thing works when session is cleared or it is false.